# linux cron: want to backup a folder

Tags: backup, cron

I would like to backup a folder using cron on a centos. The folder `c2duo_mms` is located in `/usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms`. I would like it backed ip every 1:00pm on Tuedays to my home folder `/home/sh`.

Comment: Are you backing up a folder or a file? Your question has contradictory bits. For a single file `cp` is fine, for a directory `rsync` is a better too. Please fix your question to get a precise answer.

Comment: @Caleb `c2duo_mms` it is a folder -- fixed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A good thing to do would be to create a new compressed archive in your home.

Create this script named for exmaple */home/sh/c2duo_mms_backup.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /usr/local/src/djcode/
tar zcf /home/sh/c2duo_mms-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz c2duo_mms
```

Be sure to add the executable permission to the script:

```
chmod +x /home/sh/c2duo_mms_backup.sh
```

Then add the relevant crontab entry with the *crontab -e* command:

```
0 13 * * 2 /home/sh/c2duo_mms_backup.sh
```

The script will create a new compressed archive every Tuesday with the date in the filename, so that you can keep older backups if you want. File name will look like this:

```
c2duo_mms_20110719.tar.gz
```

Comment: This is what I have been looking for!!! thanks a lot.

Comment: a better solution would be to use rsync or unison.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ crontab -e
0 13 * * 2 cp -b /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms /home/sh/
```

The `crontab -e` command should pull up the crontab file for editing in your preferred editor (Set by the EDITOR or VISUAL environment variabels). The crontab line says to run the command on the 0th minute, 13th hour, 2nd day of the week, any day of the month any year. The command itself is a simple single file copy, except that I added the `-b` argument so that `cp` makes a backup file. This should leave you with TWO backups at all times, the current one and the previous one (with a .bk extension).

**Edit:** For a folder instead of a file, try `rsync`:

```
0 13 * * 2 rsync -av /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/ /home/sh/c2duo_mms/
```

Comment: That would be "perform this on the second day of every month at 1am", right?

Comment: @caleb: For some reason it is not copying the folder to my home directory. Is there like some way that I can find what is causing this problem?

Comment: @Shehzad009: If you are using the rsync, you might make sure the target folder exists first before syncing it. Some will create it, but some won't. Also, to debug this, run th rsyncs e command manually yourself instead of from cron to see the output and make sure the backup part does what you want before sticking it in cron.

Comment: @caleb: After using `rsync e` I get this `"/home/sh/e" failed: No such file or directory (2)`. Not so sure what that e is.

Comment: The `e` is a bogus typo on your end somewhere, it doesn't appear in the command I suggested. The syntax is `rsync -[options] [source] [target]`, and it's important to end with trailing slashes on the source and targets if you are syncing directories.

Answer (score 2):

Use command `crontab -e` and add this line to your crontab:

```
0 13 * * 2 cp -pra /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms /home/sh
```